# Dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: getsockopt: connection refused in consul

Tags: tcp, consul, getsockopt

I am getting this error when I am running any `"consul members"` on consul server and clients. The port is in LISTENING state and I made sure there is no firewall blocking. I get this error when in run the same in the consul client:

> Error retrieving members: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/members:
>   dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: connectex: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it.

When I make the above request with the private IP, I get the required output. Can I change the configuration anywhere so that it listens on the private IP for requests?

Comment: `getsockopt()` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that your `consul members` lacks the option `-http-addr=...`.

**Example**

`consul members -http-addr=10.10.10.10:8500`

while assuming you use the standard port `8500` of the consul agent and that you started consul via:

`consul agent -client=10.10.10.10 #...`

**Where to find the documentation?**

- In the Consul Documentation under [Running an Agent: "Client Addr"](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/basics.html#running-an-agent):

  > If you change this address or port, you'll have to specify a -http-addr whenever you run commands such as consul members to indicate how to reach the agent.
- Or offline via `consul members -help`:

  > `http-addr=<address>
  >    The`address`and port of the Consul HTTP agent. The value can be
  >    an IP address or DNS address, but it must also include the port.
  >    This can also be specified via the CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR environment
  >    variable. The default value is http://127.0.0.1:8500. The scheme
  >    can also be set to HTTPS by setting the environment variable
  >    CONSUL_HTTP_SSL=true.`

Answer (score 0):

You may also get this when the Consul agent has failed to start. If you are running it using `systemctl`, check the logs (e.g. `/var/log/syslog`) to see if there is an error. In my case I had the wrong permissions on my certificate files.